# URL result in scanner

Tags: java, android

I'm still new at programming and I tried to build a code scanner for my project.
The problem is the result only show a text. It can't be click or direct to browser.

```
public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);
        Button scan_btn = findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
        final Activity activity = this;

        IntentIntegrator qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);

        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();
                view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null){
            if(result.getContents()==null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);




        }


    }
}
```

can somebody fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can check if `result.getContents()` start with "http" or "https" use `string.indexOf`, get it and put to your browser.

Comment: `if(result != null){
            if(result.getContents()!=null){
             if(result.getContents().indexOf("http")||result.getContents.indexOf("https")){
//what you want to do
            }
          
        }`

Comment: Okay i will test it

Comment: I can't resolve symbol on getContents in "|| result.getContents.indexOf("https"))"

Comment: oh sorry i'm wrong, use `contains`, not `indexOf`. But exactly, you should split first 4 character before set check

Comment: what do you mean by split it 4 characters before? and I still can't resolve symbol on getContents

Comment: `if(result.getContents()!=null){
         
            if(result.getContents().length()>=4){
                if(result.getContents().contains("://")){
                    String[] parts = result.getContents().split("://");
                    String part1 = parts[0];
                    if(part1.equals("http")||part1.equals("https")){
                        //this is link
                    }else{
                        //this is text
                    }
                }
              
            }
        }`
use this

Comment: i tried to it in app. When it scan a qr, it goes back to menu and when i tried to scan it again, the button didn't respond

Comment: 02-05 17:09:06.758 1446-1599/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 87K, 15% free 20573K/24007K, paused 1ms+1ms
 thats the log, when i can't press the button to scan again

Comment: this is Out of memory error. Go to build.grade, add `dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }`

Comment: where should I add it? In dependencies?

Comment: I just tried it. It still didn't fix the issue sir :(